# Can't find how to select path to run a C program

Tags: c

I am using mac OS x and have written C program using GCC compiler.
But while running the program on terminal I am being shown that `"No such file or directory found"`
Please help me how to select the path?

Answer (score 2):

run it with `$./yourProgramFile` command the `./` in the beginning is important. It means the program resides in the current directory.

Example:

```
/path/to/your/cFile $ gcc myfile.c -o myfile
/path/to/your/cFile $ ./myfile
```

Comment: I'll add that if you don't specify `-o` to gcc, it will generate a file named `a.out`. So to run it, you'll have to type `./a.out`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do one of two things 
1) Add the program's folder to the system's PATH; that way, you can call the program from any location. If it's a program you plan to use constantly, this is the best option.
Here's a way to do that: 
Open up the **.profile** file in your home directory using any text editor. 
Paste the following code anywhere in the file, preferably around the bottom of the file.

```
#make sure there's no space in the pasted code
export PATH=$PATH:path_to_the_program
```

Save it and restart your computer. That should put the program in the system's PATH.

 
2) Navigate to the folder of the program; then type

```
./program_name
```

Hope the explanation is clear and the answer helps. 
 
Make sure that when you compile the program, you should use **-o program_name** to make the program name whatever you want it to be; otherwise, the program's name will be **a.out**, which would be very confusing.

Comment: probably she don't know how to add path in PATH, you need to add that in your answer

Comment: its advisable to not mess with the 'PATH' environment variable. Imagine if the user creates a C program called 'java' and then installs java later on. One more question on stackoverflow? :-P

Comment: @Aniket; while that is a valid point, I cannot think of a valid reason not to include a consistently used program in the PATH. Any experienced user understands that a program's name must be consistent to its purpose. If you name your app Java, you are certainly short of some good programming practices.